# manage browser cache for blogspot?

Tags: html, pagespeed, blogspot

I have to improve my blogspot loading speed and i do not know where to manage cache. In normal websites it is .htaccess file. Where i have to put this code:

```
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it by adding these meta tags **below your head** section

```
<include expiration='7d' path='/assets/**.css'/> 
<include expiration='7d' path='/assets/**.js'/> 
<include expiration='3d' path='/assets/**.gif'/>
<include expiration='3d' path='/assets/**.jpeg'/>
<include expiration='3d' path='/assets/**.jpg'/>
<include expiration='3d' path='/assets/**.png'/>
```

check if it work :)

edit:
My [blog](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/) has numbers of javascripts and other heavy things runs on page startup.
but by adding this code and some other compression my blog loads quick.

Answer (score 0):

First of blogspot not provide htaccess folder ..

Your blog loading depend on images and script(CSS,other ads...etc), use lower size images or use compression tool. you can find both the tools in Google.

Answer (score 0):

Expiration headers in Blogger are server side file cache 'instructed' which is outside Blogger's user control. Adding scripts like in your example or others examples does not make any difference (yet) by modern web browsers.

Currently modern web browsers are more efficient & optimized with website cache, external resource handling, data pre-fetching etc, so the impact for the future is at a minimal - without depending (too much) on expire header checks anyway IMHO.

Which is why, for blogger pages, if optimized correctly, users can still get under 3 seconds to load its pages in full.

Please refer to [this link](https://support.google.com/blogger/forum/AAAAY7oIW-wd3xYMWd2nD0/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fblogger%2Fd3xYMWd2nD0) in Blogger Help page for more info

Answer (score -1):

i add ico extension for caching favicon

```
<include expiration='7d' path='/assets/**.ico'/>
```

Comment: Try to add some explanation to your answer.